# How to round decimal value into extract decimal point with zeros

Tags: c#, decimal, rounding

I have to round decimal value into 6 decimal places in C#. When i use sum of 0.046080 and 0.116220 with below code segment answer is 0.1623

```
DesTot = Math.Round(TotalQty + sumtot, 6);
```

But i want to display the answer as 0.162300

How can i do it with C#

Comment: With this code it Displays 6 decimal place for result that you want you should round it to 4 decimal places

Comment: It worked with code i have provided. Other answers have provided must be work since i have test the wrong variable for output.

Comment: That's your fault! Careful about output variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try format your out put display like the following

```
// this code always round number to 4 places and adds two zeros at the end.
   double TotalQty = 0.116220;
   var DesTot= Math.Round(TotalQty, 4).ToString("0.000000");
   Console.Write(DesTot);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to display it using [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b22a4x2.aspx) using the [format you wish](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).

Something like

```
DesTot.ToString("0.000000")
```

Comment: I tried but still it gives the same result. I am using c# with asp.net

Answer (score 1):

In case of your code it will be

```
var DesTot = Math.Round(TotalQty + sumtot, 6).ToString("0.000000");
```